# Own linux image on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, vmware, ec2-api-tools

I need to install linux from existing VMware VMDK on EC2. For first time I can do this manually, later I will need to do this in automated way.

Could you please help me with link to relevant documentation. Also any tips and experiences are welcome.

Why do I need this?
At my company developers and QA are running our PHP apps on a virtual machine hosted on local machine. We want to move these virtual machines to the cloud, so each developer can easily set up a sandbox in simple web interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions of [creating your own AMI](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami.html). Also check out the following articles on EBS volumes: [article1](http://4sysops.com/archives/amazon-ec2-boot-from-amazon-ebs-volumes/), [article2](http://alestic.com/2012/01/ec2-ebs-boot-recommended). Here's some steps on how to create [EBS-backed AMI instance](http://webkist.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/creating-an-amazon-ec2-ebs-ami-from-a-running-instance/).

Answer (score 4):

Amazon does not officially support importing Linux. However, an [article from 2008](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/9/1/creating-an-new-ec2-ami-from-within-vmware-or-from-vmdk-files) claims it can be done. If you try this, note [this URL](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=346996) as well.

Finally, an AWS employee posted this too:

> You can use ec2-import-volume to turn a local disk in a RAW, VMDK or VHD file format into an EBS volume in EC2. This turns a full disk, with MBR, into an EBS disk.  If the guest is PV, with the Xen PV drivers installed, you could take a snapshot and create an AMI from that snapshot, inserting the correct AKI.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually create your own images. The ec2 api tools do not support linux/esxi 5 images. I just found out after spending 2 hours on a vmware linux to amazon port.